# Calling R script using subprocess command but Library() command in r script prevents it from running

Tags: python, r, subprocess, environment-variables, package

I created an R script and I need to call the R script from Python. The R script needs some packages to run but whenever I run my python code I get the following error :

`CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/Rscript.exe', 'D:/Abhi/desktop/testing/SCRIPTS/JMOTIF/data-04-13/NewClassificationMethod.R', '51', '9', '20', '20', 'D://Abhi//desktop//testing//SCRIPTS//JMOTIF//data-04-13//PureAgri.csv', 'D://Abhi//desktop//testing//SCRIPTS//JMOTIF//data-04-13//PureForest.csv']' returned non-zero exit status 1`.

If I comment out the library call then I get no error and the script works.

As a small example the following code will not work :

```
pythonArgs = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
library(plyr)
wSize=  as.numeric(pythonArgs[1]) #as.numeric(pythonArgs[1])#Window Size
paaSize=as.numeric(pythonArgs[2])#Pax approximation size 
cat(wSize, paaSize)
```

This code will work though

```
pythonArgs = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
#library(plyr)
wSize=  as.numeric(pythonArgs[1]) #as.numeric(pythonArgs[1])#Window Size
paaSize=as.numeric(pythonArgs[2])#Pax approximation size 
cat(wSize, paaSize)
```

The following is how I am currently calling it from Python:

```
cmd = [command, path2Script] + args
x = subprocess.check_output(cmd,universal_newlines = True)
```

Comment: just out of curiosity what happens if you use `require(plyr)` rather than library?

Comment: Since there is no error msg generated just  False value the script will run until I need to use a library, when i checked the value of require(plyr) it said that it returned a FALSE value.

Comment: Does this happen with all packages? Can you examine the nature of the error using `tryCatch`?

Comment: yeah It happens with any package I try and load ( three packages). Im not familiar with the tryCatch function would it give any detail other than the error I posted in the question?

Comment: Read `?Startup` from the R console and then set the appropriate system environment variables that are missing. Your R process is not finding the correct library location. If you want to see where it is currently "looking", then include `print(.libPaths())` in your script and also do it from an R console session. I predict they will be different.

Comment: You could use it to print the error that R finds when calling `library`. If @42 suggestion doesn't see you right try something like `tryCatch(library("plyr"),error = function(e) print(e))`  to see what error message R is printing.

Comment: @42 was right, I tried loading a simple package using Library and calling it from there and it worked. Just have to install the other three packages to the main location instead of the Rstudio location and I will be set. Thank you guys very much. Can't believe it was something that simple.

Comment: You really must stop misspelling "library".

Comment: Could someone elaborate on this "answer" in the answer section, if a solution is found then please provide it, specifiying in which Language something was called from, and which code was rewritten and where.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Python's subprocess `Popen` to conditionally capture either output or error from the child process, here being the R script.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = [command, path2Script] + args
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)            
output, error = p.communicate()

if p.returncode == 0:            
    print('R OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output))            
else:                
    print('R ERROR:\n {0}'.format(error))
```

Had you run `POpen`, a more informative error message would result directly in the Python console, reminding you of the package path situation.

```
R ERROR:
 b"Error in library(plyr) : there is no package called 'plyr'\r\nExecution halted\r\n"
```

Comment: If i do this then it just returns None. Whereas the subprocess command is giving everything the R console spits out. It did help a lot for error handling though. Any idea why it is returning None though? Even if in R i just try and send back the integer 10